# Performing interpolation with QGIS in Python application?

Tags: pyqgis, interpolation

I have to make an interpolation map for river water quality, but it must be made in the Python programming language.

Can I use QGIS in a Python application?

Not Python in QGIS but QGIS in Python.

Comment: Do u mean a "stand-alone" _(external)_ python application using QGIS functionnalities ?

Comment: Of course you can, but you must setup some env paths. It depends on your operating system. It's always easier to do that on Linux and Mac than Windows.

Comment: yes, "stand-alone" (external) python. not python console in qgis.

Comment: @dmh126 how i can setup the env paths?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121395/link-qgis-to-anaconda-python-distribution-spyder-ipython-notebook-pip-scikit. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175819/can-qgis-core-work-with-external-python-distribution-such-as-anaconda